# How to return all elements from hash besides first key/value pair

Tags: ruby

I want to return all elements in a hash excluding the first key/value pair.

My experience is limited so what I'm using is `.except` because it's non-destructive.

```rb
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

# I want to return

h = {b: 2, c: 3}

# using this code

h.exclude(:a)

# or something similar
```

Comment: With rails, `except` should work.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Oh okay I didn't know it was only for Rails. Thank you!

Comment: It's part of ActiveSupport, which means it's present in Rails by default, but other apps can use it if you require ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the idea of "first" for a `Hash` is slightly fishy. It is true that `Hash`es in Ruby are insertion-ordered, [this is guaranteed by the specification](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/hash/keys_spec.rb#L4-L14), and so you can rely on it in every implementation on every platform, but *in general*, the purpose of a `Hash` is to look up values by keys, *not* rely on order.

For example, there is *no guarantee* that `:a` will be the first key in your example. It completely depends on how the `Hash` was created and in which order the keys were added.

That being said, there is an [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) method which does exactly what you want: drop the first `n` elements of an `Enumerable`, and it is unsurprisingly named [`Enumerable#drop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop).

Note that, since it is an `Enumerable` method, it knows nothing about `Hash`es, the only method it knows about, is [`#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-each). Therefore, it will return an `Array` of whatever `#each` yields, which in the case of a `Hash` is a two-element `[key, value]` pair:

```
h.drop(1)
#=> [[:b, 2], [:c, 3]]
```

Luckily, there is a method that turns an `Enumerable` of two-element `Array`s into a `Hash`, namely [`Enumerable#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h):

```
h.drop(1).to_h
#=> { b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`h.except(:a)` would work with rails/activesupport, but it requires you to know the name of the key.

Addressing first element is more tricky, because hash, as a data structure, doesn't have order for key-value pairs. But good news is that in ruby (or at least MRI/YARV) hashes do maintain insertion order and it is reflected when you iterate the key-value pairs. So you could do something like this:

```
pairs = h.to_a # get all KV pairs as an array
except_first = pairs[1..-1] # discard the first KV pair
except_first.to_h # make a hash
```

Or, more succintly

```
h.drop(1).to_h
```

Comment: ...but you do know the name of the key: `h.first.first`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `h.except(h.first.first)` is a solid [WTF-moment](https://www.osnews.com/story/19266/wtfsm/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`#shift`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-shift) with [`#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) as:

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
h.tap(&:shift) # => {:b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Comment: I like, but it is destructive.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike the idea of converting the hash to an array, manipulating the array, then converting the modified array back to a hash, so I've used [Hash#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-reject).

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

```
h.reject { |k,_| k == h.first.first }
  #=> {:b=>2, :c=>3}
```

or

```
h.reject.with_index { |_,i| i.zero? }
  #=> {:b=>2, :c=>3}
```

or

```
x = 1
h.reject { (x -= 1).zero? }
  #=> {:b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Comment: This is mostly pedantry, but the downside of this approach is that it iterates over every key-value pair in the hash even though you know the block will only return truthy in the first iteration.

Comment: @Jordan, I tried to avoid that but could not think of a (non-destructive) solution that did not enumerate all key-value pairs. One way or another, don't all solutions (including conversions to an array and from an array back to a hash) do that? Did you have something in mind?